# Views disappear when no layoutweight attribute is defined

Tags: android, android-layout

I have layout (list item):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="74dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/list_separator"
        android:id="@+id/event_separator"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="73dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/icon"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/event"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="Text text text"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/event_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="2014.05.13\n16.20:33"
            android:textColor="@color/text_faded"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:gravity="center|right"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/event_delete"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

1. the first `View` is just list separator
2. then there's an `ImageView` icon
3. text `TextView` (id.event)
4. timestamp `TextView` (id.event_time)
5. another icon 'ImageView' (id.event_delete)

It does not work, I expect to get

```
[       1      ]
[2][  3  ][4][5]
```

But I get

```
[       1      ]
[2][     3     ]
```

4 and 5 are not visible (does not fit the screen).

When I add `layout_weight="1"` it kinda works but I don't know why:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/event"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="Text text text"
    android:textColor="@color/text"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it just like you specified you are preferred to give `android:layout_weight` to all the views in the second `LinearLayout` and set `android:layout_width="0dp"` as stated [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="73dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="Text text text"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_time"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="2014.05.13\n16.20:33"
        android:textColor="@color/text_faded"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:gravity="center|right"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/event_delete"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

replace this

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

by

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

for ur `textview` `@+id/event`

you specifing `textview` width to match_parent so it will occupy all width so 4 and 5 are not visible

**edit:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="74dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/event_separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="73dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/event"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="Text text text"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/event_time"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|right"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="2014.05.13\n16.20:33"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/event_delete"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it does not work as I don't know size of text in `@+id/event`

Comment: check my edit portion i haave added xml code with weight...and in ur question u asked the reason..

Comment: u should give weight for relative layout too.,,

Comment: weight will not balance ..and u should also give weightSum for parent layout.. check my ans weightsum will divide layout by 5 weights. n sum of weight is that layout views are 5...its helps u in desighn compatibility...